# What's the difference between following two scripts written in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've following two javascript code snippets written for same purpose but only one is working. Why so?

The Working script is as below:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function Redirect(){
      window.location.assign("login.php")
    }
  </script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="cancel" id="cancel" onClick="return Redirect()">Cancel</button>
```

The non-workable code is as follows:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" value="" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='login.php'">Back</button>
```

But I want the script to be written like the second one only. I can't use first approach though it's working. Can any one please correct the second code snippet and make it workable like first script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t use a _submit_ button if you do not actually want to submit a from.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/doletono/1/

Comment: Terrible, terrible question, but that is the answer.

Comment: Submit integrates with forms.  jQuery has a form submit() thing that deals with that.

Comment: `But I want the script to be written like the second one only.` . . . actually you really don't. The first approach is a better design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of submit, try using input type button...

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" value="Back" onclick="javascript:window.location='login.php'" />
```

Answer (score -2):

1. The working script uses `window.location.assign()` whereas the non-working code tries to set `window.location.href` directly.
2. Your second example also uses a submit button whereas your first uses a regular button. Since you don't return `false` from your click handler, the form gets submitted and the fact that you set the href is void. Unless you're actually submitting the form, don't use a submit button.

Comment: @A.Wolff - I posted an incomplete answer and then filled it out. I got downvoted into oblivion before completing my answer.